# keep divs from jumping a line float

Tags: html, css

I am currently working on a responsive webpage and it's working out pretty well. Only problem is when the browser gets smaller and it hits a div, the div will jump a line. Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div id = "wrapper">
<div class = "divs">
This is div 1
</div>

<div class = "divs">
This is div 2
</div>

<div class = "divs">
This is div 3
</div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.divs{
width:100px;
float:left;
background-color: red;
margin-left: 10px;
text-align:center;
}

#wrapper{
width:400px;

}

@media screen and (max-width:399px){
#wrapper{
width:100%
}
.divs{
width: 33.33%;
}
```

[live example in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fx7s5agt/)

Comment: With small screens your divs are 1/3 of the page. But you add margin-left to them, so they take more, and the last one jump to the next line.

Comment: okay, is there a way to make my margin responsive as well?

Comment: I removed the margin and it still happened... But thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The div eventually jumps lines because you are adding a 10px margin to the left of each div.  Margins (and padding) are added to the width of an element, they are not included in it.  So a div with width of 30px and left margin of 10px will take up 40px of the screen.

The easiest solution to this is changing your width to accommodate the margin, then setting the margin to a percentage as well:

```
.divs{
   width: 100px;
   float:left;
   background-color: red;
   margin-left: 3%; /* changed margin to % so is also responsive */
   text-align:center;
}


.divs{
   width: 30%; /*reduced width to accommodate margin */
}
```